# Execute remote PHP script from Android

Tags: javascript, php, android

I'm struggling with what I think should be quite a straightforward thing to do.

Here are as many facts as I can think of to set out the situation.

Basically I have a php script residing on a remote server which I want to run from my android app.

The php does not output anything and so I have no need to read any response back from the called script.

I want the script to execute on the server (not sure if httpclient for example would attempt to execute the script locally).

The php file contains JavaScript code too.  The JavaScript does some stuff that results in an image being generated and stored on the remote server (to be collected at leisure from the android app in due course).

I do not want to use a WebView to execute the php (even if they were possible), because the ultimate aim of this is that I will use the code in an app widget, where WebViews are not available.

When I call the php script from my local browser, it runs fine, doing what it is meant to.

But when I try to use httpclient (httpput) from my android code, the php part seems to execute, but the JavaScript that follows the php in the file does not.

Any idea what I can do to get this working?  Any 'gotcha' I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: PHP is a server side language. The javascript is executed on Client side, so unless your android code can interpret the JS it won't be interpreted. It works fine on a webview because the JS is successfully interpreted on browsers :)

Comment: I never coded android but if you have JS in PHP script it will be very hard to execute it as you need JS engine to do that and httpclient is not equipped with that engine. Can you post PHP script particularly part  JS part , can it be server side ?

Comment: Just like @Copernic said, PHP is a server side language. You can call this script in various ways (i.e. API endpoint, Cron, CURL, or even send a HTTP request to the said PHP script. JS however is used to present your data that has been executed by PHP script. You can however send an HTTP request to the said PHP script and have it respond with the appropriate header (i.e if it is returning an image then set the header to be JPG/PNG/BMP/ETC). This way, you can code your java to accept the desired format.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far.  Is there any way to force the server to execute the JS?  I've been battling for days to find a way to "outsource" execution of JS, because of the limitation that you can't have a WebView in an app widget.  I know that JS is intended as a browser script, but surely there is nothing really about the language itself that should limit it in this way.  Plus, I don't need to output anything from the php or the JS to a browser window... it's just code that needs to run.  Surely there is some way I can just ask the server to execute the php *and* the JS?